# How to add image, that overlapping Bootstrap modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add close button, that overlapping Bootstrap modal.

Here what I have:
[image]

And here what I want to do: [image]

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="sign_up_header">
 <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
     <%= image_tag("/images/close_btn.png") %>
 </a>
 </div>
```

and CSS(**tried to add z-index and add top:-5px, but it is hiding behind modal**):

```
  .close{
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right:0px;
      top:0px
     }
  #sign_up{
border: 0;
width: 450px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.sign_up_header{
padding-top:10px;
padding-left: 30px;
 }
```

CSS from Bootstrap modal:

```
              .modal {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 1050;
   width: 560px;
   margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
   overflow: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
      border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
 -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
     }
```

As I found in some articles I need to add position:absolute into modal, but if I do that it won't be centered.

How I can do this ?

Comment: Could you please update post with all HTML and CSS related to modal

Comment: @Chandrakant, it will be to much code if I post all HTML. Should I find CSS from bootstrap and post it here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the overlapping effect of the close button, do this:

```
.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right:-8px;
  top:-8px
 }
```

**Edit 1**

```
.modal {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 1050;
   width: 560px;
   margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
   overflow: visible;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
   -moz-border-radius: 6px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
   background-clip: padding-box;
 }
```

Comment: Does 'image_tag()' return an image tag?

Answer (score 3):

After applying @James solution, you have to change the `.modal` property `overflow: auto` to `overflow: visible` to let the button go outside the modal but this can induce unexpected behavior.